# Двусторонняя связь для двух FormControl

Tags: angular2

Есть форма в которой  два контрола Цена без НДС и Цена с НДС, задача в том чтобы когда меняется Цена без НДС, то Цена с НДС пересчитывалась и на оборот, если пользователь вводит цену с НДС, то цена без НДС также пересчитывалась.

Обычно для связывания контролов `FormControl` есть `Observable` поле `valueChanges`, подписавшись на которое можно получить доступ к состоянию компонента в нужный момент, но проблема в том что если подписаться на оба поля, то происходит переполнение стека вызовов, так как они просто попадают в бесконечный цикл.

**UPDATE 1** Вот такой stackoverflow в JS)

```
    this.form.get('vat').valueChanges
      .subscribe(value => {
        debugger
        const result = ...пересчет
        this.form.get('isVat').setValue(result);
      });
    this.form.get('isVat').valueChanges
      .subscribe(value => {
        debugger
        const result = ...пересчет
        this.form.get('vat').setValue(result);
      });
```

> ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>       at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:202)
>       at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:132)
>       at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next
>   (Subscriber.js:76)
>       at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:53)
>       at EventEmitter.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next
>   (Subject.js:47)
>       at EventEmitter.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit
>   (core.js:13498)
>       at FormControl.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity
>   (forms.js:2897)
>       at FormControl.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControl.setValue
>   (forms.js:3275)
>       at add.component.ts:238
>       at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:13526)

Рассматривал как вариант подписаться на весь `FormGroup` также через `valueChanges`, но в таком случае я получаю всю форму и не понятно какое из полей было обновлено, так что тоже вариант не очень, не кэшировать же мне каждый раз старое значение полей...

В общем вопрос втом, как реализовать двухстороннюю связь в одном `FormGroup` двух `FormControl` так чтобы без спагетти?
Спасибо.

Comment: *проблема в том что если подписаться на оба поля, то происходит переполнение стека вызовов, так как они просто попадают в бесконечный цикл.* Алгоритмически - изменяясь, контрол должен сперва отписаться, потом измениться, потом, когда каскад изменений пройдёт (и соответственно когда сигнал по подписке от его собственного изменения будет благополучно проигнорирован), переподписаться.

Comment: `но проблема в том что если подписаться на оба поля, то происходит переполнение стека вызовов` - это что-то новенькое :D ты говоришь абстракциями, покажи хотя бы 1 кусочек кода - как ты делаешь подписку на 2 контрола, где возникает луп?

Comment: @Akina, немного непонятно, > `изменяясь, контрол должен сперва отписаться` - от чего отписаться? `valueChanges` это генератор событий из коробки, от него невозможно сначала отписаться при изменении...

Comment: @overthesanity Я не говорю о конкретной реализации. Только о том, что контрол должен распознать, что пинок об изменении, ему прилетевший, есть пинок о его собственном изменении, и доблестно его проигнорировать.

Comment: @Akina сам контрол не делает этого, так заложено уже в фундаменте 4 года назад

Comment: @overthesanity добавил код и ошибку луп возникает там где debugger стоят первый контрол вызывает обновление второго, обновление второго вызывает обновление первого и так до бесконечности пока стек вызовов не переполняется.

Comment: а, ну понятно теперь почему :D

Comment: @overthesanity а что делать?

Comment: не гони коней, я думаю :D

Comment: а какой тип у тебя в `result` - число, строка?

Comment: @overthesanity число

Comment: как вариант можно попробовать `distinctUntilChanged()`, то есть если новый результат такой же как и предыдущий - то скипнуть. Причем добавить двум потокам

Comment: @overthesanity у FormControl что то нет такого метода в Angular 6 по краиней мере?

Comment: `this.form.get('vat').valueChanges.pipe(distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe(...)`

Comment: @overthesanity не знаю почему но не помогло `import { distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';` оно?

Comment: а ты можешь маленький пример сделать на stackblitz? потому что разговором тяжело что-то сделать

Comment: @Pavel, каким способом проиходит изменение контрола? Что является источником изменений?